# Scala: What is opt keyword?

Tags: scala

What is opt keyword in following code?

```
import scala.util.control.Exception._
import java.net._

val s = "http://www.scala-lang.org/"
val x1 = catching(classOf[MalformedURLException]) opt new URL(s)
val x2 = catching(classOf[MalformedURLException], classOf[NullPointerException]) either new URL(s)
```

[scala.util.control.Exception](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/util/control/Exception$.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not a *keyword*, it's a *method* imported from `scala.util.control.Exception._`, here's its definition and Scaladoc:

```
/** Apply this catch logic to the supplied body, mapping the result
 *  into `Option[T]` - `None` if any exception was caught, `Some(T)` otherwise.
 */
def opt[U >: T](body: => U): Option[U] = toOption(Some(body))
```

Comment: Thanks you for your help!

Answer (score 7):

It's not a keyword, it's a method, defined in `Catch[T]`, which the result type of `catching()`. See its doc at http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.util.control.Exception$$Catch@opt[U%3E:T](body:=%3EU):Option[U]

The above code is equivalent to the following, where we use `.` syntax to call the methods `opt` and `either`:

```
val s = "http://www.scala-lang.org/"
val x1 = catching(classOf[MalformedURLException]).opt(new URL(s))
val x2 = catching(classOf[MalformedURLException], classOf[NullPointerException]).either(new URL(s))
```

Comment: Two rather similar answers posted at almost exactly the same time, both upvoted - what's the etiquette - what do we do now? :))

Comment: AFAIK Stack Overflow does not allow one to accept two answers to the same question, so there is no fair solution. The least unfair would be to choose at random which one to accept, and upvote the other one ...

Comment: Another "strategy" I've seen being used sometimes is to accept the answer of the user with the least reputation.

Comment: Thanks you for your help!